# which tense to use for emphasis?

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous, emphasis

If someone asks me : what have you been doing this afternoon and I want to say that I have been reading the newspaper, emphasizing the activity, how I have been occupying myself, not the result, even though I have finished reading the entire paper, can I use the perfect progressive or do I have to use the present perfect: What have you been doing? I have read the paper/ I have been reading the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progressive or continuous indicates ongoingness or repetition.

> I've been repairing the shed's roof this afternoon.

does not mean that the shed is now repaired, only that you have bee doing something towards the repair, whereas

> I've repaired the shed's roof.

indicates that the shed's roof is now ready to be rained on.

P.S. Let's take a real world situation.

If you are asked

> What have you been doing all afternoon?

if would be improper to reply

> I have brushed my teeth.

since the question wants either a single activity that occupied you throughout the afternoon, or a list of the activities which have occupied you.

So, you could say, in response to the question "What have you been doing":

> I have brushed my teeth and I have paid a few bills and I have given the dog a bath.

or

> I have been playing FIFA.

If you say

> I have been brushing my teeth all afternoon.

people will think you have an obsessive-compulsive disorder.

Comment: Yes, I understand. How about brushing your teeth? For example: what have you been doing in the bathroom? Is it possible to say I have been brushing my teeth, when you mean that you have brushed all of your teeth?

Comment: See my P.S. which addresses the question in your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I haven`t made myself clear enough. This is a big misunderstanding, funny though. Forget all afternoon, I`ve been in the bathroom 5 minutes. What I mean is can I say I have been brushing my teeth ( for 2 minutes ) when I have obviously brushed all of my teeth, to emphasize the activity, not the result.

Comment: @anouk: Question: *Have you finished brushing your teeth?*  ANSWER: *Yes, I **have brushed** my teeth.*  A progressive/continuous in the reply would not answer the question.  You can say *I have been brushing my teeth* to indicate what you *have been doing* for some length of time. It has been an ongoing activity.  The progressive/continuous is **silent** with respect to completion.

Answer (score 1):

Question: What have  you been doing [up to the point where I am asking you this question].

- I've been reading the paper. [up until this point in time in the present].

Question: What have you done this afternoon?

- I've read the paper. OR I read the paper. Either is fine.

The first is general and merely states it was in the past without any more information.

The second is more specific and implies a **specific act** that is finished.

In practical terms, they are  both acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don`t understand what you mean at all. By the first and the second do you mean your examples? Do you mean that "I read the paper" is a specific act and "I have read" is not specific? Both are acceptable"  do you mean your examples or mine? I thought the progressive could also be used for an act that has recently finished. I`m sorry, but I`m really confused.

Comment: @anouk, I mean the PP continuous versus the PP and the SP. I've been reading versus I have read/I read. Both means: PP and SP.  I have read is not specific, it's just ***signalling*** that something happened in the  past. A specific past action is signalled by SP. I've been reading signals: up to this point in time when I am speaking "to you". |_________| present. The line represents: have been [verb]